# How can I make Thunderbird on Windows open links in a different browser?

Tags: windows, browser, thunderbird

I don't want Thunderbird to use the default browser when I click on links.  How can I configure it to use a different browser?

Windows 10
Thunderbird 78

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Options > General > Config Editor
2. Set network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http (and https) to true
3. Find an http link in an email.
4. A pop-up will allow you to choose the application to use for HTTP or HTTPS content.
5. Click "Choose" and enter the path to your preferred browser's executable
6. Select "Remember my choice" and click "Open link"
7. Repeat steps 3-6 for an https link instead.